# Dynamic list of items from Cursor into LinearLayout, without using a ListView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-cursoradapter

I'd like to display a few (5-ish) items from a Cursor in a list, and I'd like to keep it in sync with the content of the cursor (which in turn points to a database), but I don't want to use ListViews. Instead, I'd like to populate a plain old LinearLayout.

I seem to understand that I need to create a custom CursorAdapter and override the newView() and bindView() methods. What I don't understand is who is responsible for iterating over the cursor's items (does the CursorAdapter do it? Should my code do it?), how do the views for each item get parented to the LinearLayout and who is responsible for creating new views for new items in the cursor or removing views for items that are no longer available through the cursor?

Somehow I have a hunch that the CursorAdapter does already most of the work, but I can't quite put together all the pieces of the puzzle. Do I just inflate a row layout in newView() and add it to the LinearLayout directly? And how does a row gets removed if the cursor no longer has the associated data?

Thanks for your help!

Manu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would do the following:

- Create a custom class, a subclass of LinearLayout, just to make it simple. Let's call it MyList
- You pass the CursorAdapter instance to this class (eg. create a setAdapter method)
- When receiving the adapter, MyList will register for data changes (CursorAdapter.registerDataSetObserver). When the data set changes, call a method "populate"
- When receiving the adapter, also call "populate" directly, to get the initial contents
- Implement MyList.populate:
  ** call removeAllViews
  ** for each item (iterate through the cursor) call addView(CursorAdapter.newView(getContext(), cursor, this))

That's it in short. Of course later on you might want to optimize it, and keep the old views and use CursorAdapter.bindView instead, so you wouldn't need to create new heavy java objects.

Comment: It all seems sensible, but doesn't the CursorAdapter already has some iteration logic already? I mean, in normal circumstances, i.e. using a ListView, when does the getView(), newView() and bindView() get called? Doesn't it happen on a per-cursor-item basis? Shouldn't I just override those method then?

Comment: No, it's the ListView which is iterating, since the ListView knows the "viewing window", the set of items which are visible, so the ListView initiates the newView() or bindView() calls. To speed it up, it caches the Views. So the first time it creates a view, it must call newView(). Then when the view is not visible any more (the user scrolled away), it moves it to the cache. Then when another item becomes visible, it reuses the item from the cache, and calls bindView() only to update the data in the view.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It helps. I guess I remain a little confused by the underlying architectural choice. That is, why is the CursorAdapter (partially) responsible for views? Isn't that wholly competence of the ListView? Wouldn't have made more sense to have newView(), getView() and bindView() in the ListView class, extend that and pass the cursor directly to it? I guess I'm not really understanding why the Adapter is there in the middle when extending any View class would do the trick. =?

Answer (score 1):

The CursorAdapter allows you to navigate a large list without having to have all the items loaded into memory. If you are just going to have a small handful of items then I would just iterate over them in your activity and update your view accordingly (adding views, setting text values, showing/hiding, etc.)

Comment: I thought it was the ListView who took care of _not_ loading in memory unnecessary views. And of course there is the Cursor that at any given time is only pointing to one item internally. In this context what does the CursorAdapter do then?

Comment: All adapters provide an interface between a ListView and data, virtualizing a (potentially) large list into a small set of viewable list items. CursorAdapter does this by moving a cursor back and forth through the results of a query. If you were actually using a ListView I might still use the CursorAdapter just because it's so simple to hook up, but when you're contemplating using a CursorAdapter with a non-ListView Layout and only for a handful of items I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to confirm the thoughts I expressed in the comment to Pal: given the small number of items to display a custom View and/or a custom Activity such as the one suggested by @Kurtis would be sufficient, bypassing the CursorAdapter entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html). When ever there is a change in your content it will update automatically.

Comment: This solution sounds neat and simple. I'll see where this thinking leads me in the next few days!

Comment: So easy in fact I've edited my response to include and example! :)

Comment: I did try this solution but it seemed to create more problems. I.e. I had to use Cursor.requery() in onResume() because it seems that the content observer I registered is only notified when the Activity is running. But eventually I also changed the UI design and this will allow me to use a ListAdapter and a ListView again.

Comment: @manu3d I don't know what i was thinking. I've updated my answer to the correct way of doing things.